# what happens when I reinstall my android application

Tags: android

what happens when I re install  my application without removing it first?

what I'm looking for is, when my application is currently running, and I do a re install, the

Activity.OnDestroy() isn't called.

I have to do something before the application closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onPause()`. According to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle), `onPause()` is the only method that is **guaranteed** to be called. The latter ones, `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` might not be called.

However, AFAIK there's no way to tell **why** your application is being paused (e.g. to be reinstalled). The only way to detect a reinstall is like this:

1. Use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store the version code of your app.
2. When the app starts, check the stored version code against the current version code (use the [`PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) for the latter). If there's a difference, do whatever you need to do when the app is upgraded and overwrite the previous version code in `SharedPreferences`.

Also note that this requires the version code to bump between reinstalls. If you're just doing `adb install -r` with a package that has the same version code, there's no way to tell.

Comment: I'm adding a flag to know if my app causes the onPause or not. so I eliminate most or even all of the scenarios

Comment: That might not be a good idea. Your app can also be paused by: a phone call, the user hitting back / home, the user clicking on a notification, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Read description of lifecycle - onDestroy() is not guaranted to be called -  the only reliable callback  is onPause() -   so you have to do your something there.